# Es posible editar el hash de un archivo por uno personalizado?

Tags: hash, md5

necesito controlar la integridad de un archivo, corroborando su Hash, para detectar modificaciones en el mismo. Existen herramientas como MD5_Hash_Changer que cambian el hash, pero generando uno completamente nuevo automáticamente. Sin embargo, quiero modificar el hash del archivo modificado por el hash original.

Es posible? de que forma?.

Gracias!.

Comment: ¿Quieres restituir el hash original en un archivo cuyo contenido ha sido modificado?

Answer (score 0):

Pues en teoría no.... lo que quieres es justamente *romper* el hash. Si se pudiera hacer eso, entonces podrías modificar archivos de los que se tiene el md5 justamente para verificar que *no* han cambiado. Ya md5 se sabe que no es el hash mas seguro, pero no se si ya estamos en el punto en el que puedes decir: voy a cambiar un `.` por una `,` y de forma determinística saber que si vas a otro byte específico del archivo y colocando otro valor para *balancear* el cambio que quieres hacer vas a obtener el md5 original.